# jQuery Cycle2 transition plugin doesn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-cycle2

I have a issue with this plug in of jquery cycle2.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Usare jQuery Cycle2 (2) | Sintesi-design.it</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fonts/font.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/template.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="slideshow" 
data-cycle-fx=carousel
data-cycle-timeout=0
data-cycle-carousel-visible=5
data-cycle-next="#next"
data-cycle-prev="#prev"
data-cycle-pager="#pager"
>
<img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach1.jpg">
<img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach2.jpg">
<img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach9.jpg">
</div>

<div class=center>
<a href=# id=prev>&lt;&lt; Prev </a>
<a href=# id=next> Next &gt;&gt; </a>
</div>

<div class="cycle-pager" id=pager></div>

<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cycle2.carousel.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

I downloded the code of the plug in like say the documentation.
The others effects works, only this with transition not, someone know why?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ska2hjr0/

According to documentation:

> cycle-slideshow is a special classname which tells Cycle2 to
>   auto-initialize the slideshow when the page is loaded.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/basic.php

Another method, add jquery code to page: `$( '.slideshow' ).cycle();`
But auto initialization is even better.

Comment: ? However, you can start slideshow manually, too, as explained -> $('your-selector').cycle(); (+ options, if you need it).http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

Comment: i need the same of your jsfiddle but i dont show the images, what i need to add?

Comment: Sorry i am not sure that i understand... You want to cycle something else, not images? Put that elements (div,p,span...whatever) INSIDE slideshow div, and that's it... btw, here is demo with manual initializing...http://jsfiddle.net/ska2hjr0/1/

Comment: i need to show the images at page load, what i need to add? your example in the jsfiddle it's perfect!

Comment: Check css - and change it to fit your needs.